# Why can't I store Japanese UTF-8 characters in char array in Java?

Tags: java, string, unicode, utf-8

I have a string "1234567(Asics (アシックスワーキング) )". It has unicode character, some are a part of ASCII and some are not. What java does is that it takes one byte for ASCII character and two bytes for other unicode characters.

Some part of my program is unable to process the string in this format. So I wanted to encode the values into escaped sequences.

So the string

> "1234567(Asics (アシックスワーキング) )"

would map to

> "\u0031\u0032\u0033\u0034\u0035\u0036\u0037\u0028\u0041\u0073\u0069\u0063\u0073\u0020\u0028\u30a2\u30b7\u30c3\u30af\u30b9\u30ef\u30fc\u30ad\u30f3\u30b0\u0029\u0020\u0029"

.

I wrote this function to do this :-

```
public static String convertToEscaped(String utf8) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    char[] str = utf8.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder unicodeStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    char charValue = str[i];
    int intValue = (int) charValue;
    String hexValue = Integer.toHexString(intValue);
    unicodeStringBuilder.append("\\u");
    for (int length = hexValue.length(); length < 4; length++) {
        unicodeStringBuilder.append("0");
    }
    unicodeStringBuilder.append(hexValue);
    }
    return unicodeStringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

This was working fine outside of my program but caused issues inside my program. This was happening to the line `char[] str = utf8.toCharArray();`
Somehow I was loosing my japanese unicode characters and this was happening because t was dividing these characters into 2 in the char array.

So I decided to go with `byte []` instead.

```
    public static String convertToEscaped(String utf8) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    byte str[] = utf8.getBytes();
    StringBuilder unicodeStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length - 1 ; i+=2){
    int intValue = (int) str[i]* 256 + (int)str[i+1];
    String hexValue = Integer.toHexString(intValue);
    unicodeStringBuilder.append("\\u");
    for (int length = hexValue.length(); length < 4; length++) {
        unicodeStringBuilder.append("0");
    }
    unicodeStringBuilder.append(hexValue);
    }
    return unicodeStringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

> Output :
>   \u3132\u3334\u3536\u3738\u2841\u7369\u6373\u2028\uffffe282\uffffa1e3\uffff81b7\uffffe283\uffff82e3\uffff81af\uffffe282\uffffb8e3\uffff82af\uffffe283\uffffbbe3\uffff81ad\uffffe283\uffffb2e3\uffff81b0\u2920

But this is also wrong as I am merging two single byte characters into one. What can I do to overcome this?

Comment: _"What java does is that it takes one byte for ASCII character and two bytes for other unicode characters."_ What do you mean by this? Each character should be represented by a `char` which is 16 bits in Java.

Comment: This is not the case everywhere. Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988204/is-a-character-1-byte-or-2-bytes-in-java

Comment: Java `char`s still uses 16-bit Unicode. That answer just says the a `ObjectOutputStream` uses a different encoding internally, as well as that UTF-8 can use more than 1 byte. But if you're doing I/O, you can usually specify the encoding you want.

Comment: Then why is the byte[] encoding coming out wrong?

Comment: When you call `getBytes` you can also specify the charset (encoding), but if you do not, it will use your systems default.

Comment: @JornVernee Yes, when you run it, default is your default; When I run it, default is my default. While this might have been useful in the 1990s, it should be a very deliberate and rare decision now, which, as you point out, is why it's not working out for the question asker.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know your other code's specific requirements. But my advice is to not reinvent the wheel and use the built-in encoding capabilities of the API.

For instance call `getBytes` with either `StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE` or `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE` based on the endian-ness you need:

```
String s = "1234567(Asics (アシックスワーキング) )";

byte[] utf8 = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] utf16 = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE); // high order byte first

System.out.println(s.length()); // 28
System.out.println(utf8.length); // 48
System.out.println(utf16.length); // 56 (2 bytes for each char)
```

Comment: I tried UTF-16, it also works outside ( http://ideone.com/HihouG ) but in my program, it converts these japanese character to 4 bytes. Do not know why this is happening :/

Comment: Maybe the Strings are in some other form, I'm just logging to see what's inside.

Comment: @DhruvChandhok How are you getting the strings then? I just copy and pasted it from your example.

Comment: @DhruvChandhok It's true that some characters can take up 4 bytes under UTF-16, I assumed that you weren't using those since you were converting into 16-bits per char yourself. You could also use UTF-32BE through `Charset.forName("UTF-32BE")`, which would make all characters 4 bytes.

Comment: the problem is with how the strings are getting populated. I tried hard coding the above string and it works. Though, on printing the string, "1234567(Asics (アシックスワーキング) )" is printed, it may be in some other form. Investigating it, never faced this earlier. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

As they commented above the internal representation of string in java is utf-16. Found

Character.codePointAt() and Integer.toHexString() that are helpful in your case.

Renamed the parameter to just theString, also removed the throws Exception clause from your original method since no exception was thrown. (it is bad practice in general to throw these generic exceptions)

```
public static String convertToEscaped(String theString) {
    char[] charArr = theString.toCharArray();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
        String hexString = Integer.toHexString(Character.codePointAt(charArr, i));

        sb.append("\\u");

        if (hexString.length() == 2) {
            sb.append("00");
        }
        sb.append(hexString);
    }
    return sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: "Internal representation of string in java is utf-16" was true but, internals being internals, it is now only true at the API level. Some implementations trade time for space by using [compact strings](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) internally and converting to UTF-16 when the user code requires it. Or put another way, Java uses UTF-16 but the JVM might not.